# How can I space out these elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to space out my `h3` elements to look like this (I will add the background for prices later on):

[image]

but I am not entirely sure of how to do so. Please can you tell me the best way to do that?

I create a JSFiddle of this example which can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/MBeQ2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change  `H3` to `<ul> <li>..`, but it's not a real rule.

Here is one example using pretty much the same HTML

[***try This link***](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/MBeQ2/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `padding: 10px;` to your css code refering to h3 tag. Of Course 10px is just an example;)